# Calculating new variable in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a variable with the same value for each case. Here is the R code that I've tried writing using mutate:

```
dataset1 %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(
  pop2 = 55000000
)
```

---

```
dataset1 %>%
  mutate(pop2 = 55000000)
```

---

They are both creating new variables within the dataframe. Can I also write this to the dataset?

Comment: Btw: if you want to learn more about `R` - this is a really good online available book: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. You want to add a column to the data frame and then save the data frame back somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can.

```
dataset1 <- dataset1 %>% mutate(pop2 = 55000000)
```

Comment: Or if itt is to create in place, use the `%<>%` operator from `magrittr`

Comment: That's true. It has the disadvantage that it is harder to see in the code, though. This is personal preference, I guess. ;)

Comment: WOW! I did not know this exists, @akrun ! so useful!

Comment: Great! Thank you :)